# How could I make this code better (eliminate for loop)

Tags: javascript

Problem: I know this code with the for loop isn't the best and is quite simple, but I also have heard that nesting for each's is a bad idea. So how could I edit this code to be more elegant?

```
     allowedCardBrands.forEach((card) => {
            let cardInfo = {}
            for (var i = 0; i < cardDefinitionsResponse.length; i++ ){
                if (card === cardDefinitionsResponse[i].brand){
                    cardInfo.brand = cardDefinitionsResponse.brand;
                    cardInfo.issuer = cardDefinitionsResponse.issuers[0].name;
                    cardInfo.brandLogo = cardDefinitionsResponse.logo;
                    cardInfo.issuerLogo = cardDefinitionsResponse.issuers[0].logo;
                }
            }
            allowedCardLogos.push(cardInfo);
        })
```

Comment: Where did you hear that nesting loops is a bad idea? It's fine, you aren't really doing anything very intensive in the deepest loop. Now, if you had 5-6 nested loops, and in the deepest ones you were calling 15 functions or something, you may have a problem

Comment: Don't believe the hype. `for` loops are fine.

Comment: If there's a need for for loop, you have to use for loop. simple...

Comment: For loops are fine, but nested for loops like this are O(n*m) complexity.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes, this is bad design. there's no reason to re-loop through the same data every time. the inner loop is not a sub-set of the outer-loop, which makes it poor design.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing what some of the other variables are, but this does seem off. Also, the i variable is not used in determining the data obtained. Therefore, either you should have a break statement, or your code is broken.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with these nested loops is that you are repeatedly looping over the same `cardDefinitionsResponse` collection for each item of the `allowedCardBrands` array. One solution is to loop through `definitionsByBrand` just once and build a fast lookup structure so that the `allowedCardBrands` loop can complete much quicker.

```
const definitionsByBrand = cardDefinitionsResponse.reduce((lookup, item) => {
  lookup.set(item.brand, item);
  return lookup;
}, new Map());

const allowedCardLogos = allowedCardBrands.map(brand => {
  const match = definitionsByBrand.get(brand);
  return match
    ? {
        brand: match.brand,
        issuer: match.issuers[0].name,
        brandLogo: match.logo,
        issuerLogo: match.issuers[0].logo
      }
    : {}
});
```

Comment: This seems a lot more complicated for something so simple IMHO

Comment: If the arrays are small enough that you know you don't have to care about performance, you can stick with nested for loops, but for larger structures this will bring complexity down from `O(n * m)` to `O(n) + O(m)`

Comment: its not more complicated. its more simple. it avoids re-looping through the same data n times.

Comment: The code itself seems more complicated, regardless of how it's technically more simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
const allowedCardLogos = allowedCardBrands
  .map(card => {
    return cardDefinitionsResponse
      .filter(response => response.brand === card)
      .map(filteredResponse => ({
        brand: filteredResponse.brand,
        issuer: filteredResponse.issuers[0].name,
        brandLogo: filteredResponse.logo,
        issuerLogo: filteredResponse.issuers[0].logo
      }));
  })
  .flat();
```